# Cannot get environment value

Tags: go, cgo

When I use setenv to set an environment value, it cannot be got by os.Getenv. Can someone tell me why?

```
package main
/*
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
*/
import "C"

import "os"
import "strings"
import "fmt"

func main()  {
    C.setenv(C.CString("CSET"), C.CString("1.1.1.1:1111"), C.int(1)) //call setenv 
    C.puts(C.getenv(C.CString("CSET")))  // call getenv

    addrs := strings.Split(os.Getenv("CSET"), ";")
    fmt.Printf("addrs = %v\n", addrs)

    os.Setenv("GOSET", "2.2.2.2:2222")
    C.puts(C.getenv(C.CString("GOSET")))
}
```

---

```
dingrui@dingrui-PC:~/Projects/Temp$ go run env.go 
1.1.1.1:1111
addrs = []
2.2.2.2:2222
```

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27693) and [Go os.Getenv() doesn't see variables set by C.setenv()](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *feature* of `Getenv`.

In the source file [`syscall/env_unix.go`](https://golang.org/src/syscall/env_unix.go), we see that a copy of the environment variables is made in the program initialization phase (`envs []string = runtime_envs()`).

This copy is not updated if you modify the program environment variables in the background using the C functions.

Unfortunately, there is no way around this feature.